# How do you change opacity of boxes surrounding text in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

Right now I have already added a box behind some text by using this code:

```
    `.alphabet {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        width: 50%;
        height: 200px;
        padding: 25px;
        margin: 25px;
    }`
```

It is working fine, but is there a way to change this box's opacity?

Comment: There is a CSS property called `opacity` which you can use here. Try `opacity: 0.5` or whichever value you wanted.

Comment: use background-color:rgba(100,100,100, 0.5). The last number is the opacity for the background color, where 0 is transparent and 1 is fully opaque.